# Question about convergence in integration by parts.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> I have the following integral :
>
> $$ I = \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^4}}{1+x^2}dx \approx 0.711959  $$

---

I integrate by parts :

$$u = \sqrt{1+x^2}= A$$
$$du = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=B$$

$$dv =\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x^2}=C $$
$$v = \sqrt{2}*tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}})-sin^{-1}(x)=D$$

to obtain :

$$ I = AD\Biggr|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}(DB) dx $$

the problem i have is that the limits of AD do not converge due to the arctangent but according to wolfram alpha the integral of DB converges. So where am i making a mistake???

Thank you kindly for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

$\left. AD \right|_{x = 1}$ is undefined, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} AD$ is undefined, but you only need $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} AD = \frac{\pi(\sqrt{2}-1)}{\sqrt{2}}$.

In fact all you *need* is
$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} AD = 0  $$
and 
$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} AD = \frac{\pi(\sqrt{2}-1)}{\sqrt{2}}  \text{.}  $$

When transforming the bounds of integration, you only need the existence of the limit from the side on which the interval of integration lies.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with evaluating $AD$ at either $1$ or $0$

Note that arctangent approaches $\pi/2$ at infinity.